# get result type in operations with libgccjit

Tags: c++, jit, libgccjit

I am implementing a jit compiler with libgccjit and am stuck when trying to retrieve the result of a binary operation.

It isn't getting the result that's the issue, but declaring the type of the result.

I have two `gcc_jit_rvalue`s and want to perform a simple binary op on them.

These two rvalues's could have any type.

For the fourth parameter of [`gcc_jit_context_new_binary_op`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/topics/expressions.html#gcc_jit_context_new_binary_op) I have to specify a result type.

Given that I don't know the types of the rvalue's but can get the `gcc_jit_type*` of them, how can I find out the standard C result type (the result type GCC would use when compiling a C expression `a + b`) of the expression?

I know I can write a bunch of `if` and `else` or `switch` statements to go over every single god-damn combination of integer and float and return what would be expected in C, but that is a *lot* of typing I really don't want to have to do.

Is there some easier way I can find the result type GCC would use if it were compiling C code?